# Ошибка при синтаксическом анализе пакета

Tags: java, android

Хочу обновлять приложение минуя play market и подобные.

Написал код, разрешил в системе установку из недостоверных источников, в том числе и для своего приложения.

Добавил в manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Запускаю установку вот так:

```
private void runInstallIntent() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"app-release.apk");
    Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,data);
    intent.setDataAndType(data,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Но выходит уведомление "Ошибка при синтаксическом анализе пакета", клавиша `ок` и более ничего.

Сначала я подумал что проблема в самом `APK`. Перепроверил, и даже по новой сделал подписанный APK файл, перезалил его на устройство, но результат остался прежним.

Нашел на устройстве стандартный проводник, через него зашел в папку `Download` запустил установку, и оно нормально обновилось!

Что я делаю не так?

**P.S.** Android 9, API 28

**UPD.** Приложение устанавливалось сразу через APK, в маркеты не заливалось. И успешно устанавливается/обновляется через встроенный проводник.

**UPD2.** Так и не понял, почему когда используется `FileProvider` не происходит установка/обновление.

Решил пока временно не использовать `FileProvider`, и чтобы не ловить исключение `FileUriExposedException` на API>24 применил [следующий хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437379/9271527)

```
try{
    Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
    m.invoke(null);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Comment: Если вы ставили приложение через PlayMarket, с флешки вы его не установите, и наоборот

Comment: вы пытаетесь именно установить с нуля или обновить? при обновлении может быть ошибка подобного плана при попытке downgrade.

Comment: @ArtyMorris, про это я знаю. В маркете этого приложения нет и не будет. Только подписанные `release` версии `apk`, которые и устанавливаются.

Comment: @ermak0ff установить с нуля я могу только через "проводники". Мне интересен именно механизм обновления (установка новой версии) приложения через `apk` файл.

Comment: А вы файл-провайдера в манифесте прописали? Правильно прописали? У вашей апы есть разрешение на доступ к самому файлу?

Comment: @woesss, прописал. Вроде бы правильно, т.к. если меняю там параметры в лог лезут ошибки доступа. У приложения есть доступ к этому файлу. Оно (приложение) и сохранило его туда по воздуху.